# Create file from text file line by line with php

Tags: php, file, text

Need some advice on how to proceed with this project..

I have a text file, that is formatted like this..

```
    0101    URL_Link_01
0205    URL_Link_02
0566    URL_Link_03
etc.. 
etc...
```

I need to create file from with the file name being the first 4 digits.. ie 0101.html
Also to add the string URL_Link string as a url in the file above..

and then next line do the same.. so for the above example i would have 3 files saved, with names as 0101.html, 0205.html, and 0566.html

What would the best way to do this be using php. Any help most appreciated.

Comment: Where are you stuck?  Have you looked into how to read from a file?  How to concatenate strings?  How to create a file?  How to write to a file?  These all seem like easily searchable pieces of functionality.  What did you try and what isn't working?

Comment: So far i can read from a file.. using 

$section = file_get_contents('file.txt', NULL, NULL, 5, 30);

but not sure how to print that info to screen, and then go to next line and next line and so on

Answer (score 0):

I think, from what i think you need, it's best to use GET, like www.url.com?pageID=0101 and with the variable pageID you can grab the data from database or something.

To make it look nice you can use this rewrite rule:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /?pageID=$1 [L]
```

What this rule does is, it let's you navigate to: www.url.com/1010.html and it will be "rewrtitten" to www.url.com?pageID=1010

Comment: I was thinking the same before to, but the data is in the text file, or i could make it a csv file if thats easier.

Comment: maybe it's doable with a regex, how is the data formatted/saved?

Comment: data is inputted straight into notepad on windows, or could be done as a csv..

Dont know much about regex, will look into that option now.